# Git credentials issue on windows

Tags: git, windows-10, gitlab, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have few repositories hosted on corporate gitlab server. Everything was fine until yesterday.
Suddenly all of my public repositories started to return 403 error, and the private ones cannot be cloned by git with error like this: `fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/my/project.git/' not found`.
I'm using Windows 10, I've tried to run exactly the same commands from Ubuntu on the same PC (Windows subsystem for Linux), and everything is working fine for the same directory.

The command I'm trying:

```
Projects> git clone http://gitlab.my-company.com/my/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/my/project.git/' not found
```

Here is the output from git log:

```
18:02:48.454054 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/my/project.git'
18:02:48.580533 run-command.c:627       trace: run_command: 'remote-http' 'origin' 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/my/project.git'
18:02:48.658654 git.c:576               trace: exec: 'git-remote-http' 'origin' 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/my/project.git'
18:02:48.658654 run-command.c:627       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-http' 'origin' 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/my/project.git'
18:02:48.945121 run-command.c:627       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
18:02:49.054428 git.c:576               trace: exec: 'git-credential-manager' 'get'
18:02:49.054428 run-command.c:627       trace: run_command: 'git-credential-manager' 'get'
18:02:49.163803 ...\Common.cs:527       trace: [Main] git-credential-manager (v1.14.0) 'get'
18:02:49.241926 ...\Where.cs:240        trace: [FindGitInstallations] found 1 Git installation(s).
18:02:49.241926 ...Configuration.cs:405 trace: [LoadGitConfiguration] git All config read, 19 entries.
18:02:49.241926 ...\Where.cs:240        trace: [FindGitInstallations] found 1 Git installation(s).
18:02:49.241926 ...Configuration.cs:405 trace: [LoadGitConfiguration] git All config read, 19 entries.
18:02:49.288801 ...\Common.cs:77        trace: [CreateAuthentication] detecting authority type for 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/'.
18:02:49.288801 ...uthentication.cs:137 trace: [GetAuthentication] not github.com, authentication creation aborted.
18:02:49.288801 ...\Common.cs:172       trace: [CreateAuthentication] authority for 'http://gitlab.my-company.com/' is basic with NTLM=Auto.
18:02:49.304424 ...seSecureStore.cs:138 trace: [ReadCredentials] credentials for 'git:http://gitlab.my-company.com' read from store.
18:02:49.304424 ...\Common.cs:559       trace: [QueryCredentials] credentials found.
```

Exactly the same command on built-in ubuntu works fine, so it is not a problem with network or bad URL.

Looks like some issue with credentials manager, but I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried to reinstall git client on windows (`git version 2.16.1.windows.4`).

Is there any way to wipe all of the git credentials?

Comment: Are you sure it is http and not https? Could it be that you just missed the 's' on windows?

Comment: No, it is exactly the same command pasted into two different windows. The URL is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by uninstalling git and installing again without credentials manager.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10. To update your credentials, go to Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> Generic Credentials. Find the credentials related to your git account and edit them to use the updated passwords.